# Mostrar Pop Up de una imagen

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap, magnific-popup

Mi pregunta en si es como hacer que una imagen aparezca cada vez que se  carga una pagina html, adjunto código e imagen de ejemplo:

[image: Pop UP de Imagen HTML]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<link href="css/magnific-poup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/MessagePopUp.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   //Popup Notificación de Informacion de Seguridad. Elvin Diaz 21/04/2017
   $.magnificPopup.open({
     showCloseBtn:true,
     closeOnBgClick:true,
     enableEscapeKey: true,
     closeOnContentClick: true,
     closeBtnInside: true,
     type:'image',
     image: {
      markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
         '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
         '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
        '</div>',
      tError: 'La imagen no puede cargarse.'
     },
     items: {
      src: 'res/bootstrap.png'
     }
    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
!function(o){o.MessagePopUp=function(e){var r="",i=!1,t=null,n="_self",a="20px",p="inherit",d=null,s="90%",c="",l=!1,h=null,m="_self",f="20px",g="inherit",u=1e3,v=null,x=600,U="white",P="250px",b="auto",z="20px",A="black",w="arial",y={header:{nombre:r,enlace:i,url:t,ventana:n,size:a,color:p},imagen:{url:d,ancho:s},footer:{nombre:c,enlace:l,url:h,ventana:m,size:f,color:g},propiedades:{color:U,ancho:P,alto:b,margenDerecho:z,colorLetra:A,font:w},tiempoInicio:u,tiempoSalida:v,tiempoTransicion:x},T=o.extend(y,e);void 0!==T.header.nombre&&(r=T.header.nombre),void 0!==T.header.enlace&&(i=T.header.enlace),void 0!==T.header.url&&(t=T.header.url),void 0!==T.header.ventana&&(n=T.header.ventana),void 0!==T.header.size&&(a=T.header.size),void 0!==T.header.color&&(p=T.header.color),void 0!==T.imagen.url&&(d=T.imagen.url),void 0!==T.imagen.ancho&&(s=T.imagen.ancho),void 0!==T.footer.nombre&&(c=T.footer.nombre),void 0!==T.footer.enlace&&(l=T.footer.enlace),void 0!==T.footer.url&&(h=T.footer.url),void 0!==T.footer.ventana&&(m=T.footer.ventana),void 0!==T.footer.size&&(f=T.footer.size),void 0!==T.footer.color&&(g=T.footer.color),void 0!==T.tiempoInicio&&(u=T.tiempoInicio),void 0!==T.tiempoSalida&&(v=T.tiempoSalida),void 0!==T.tiempoTransicion&&(x=T.tiempoTransicion),void 0!==T.propiedades.color&&(U=T.propiedades.color),void 0!==T.propiedades.ancho&&(P=T.propiedades.ancho),void 0!==T.propiedades.alto&&(b=T.propiedades.alto),void 0!==T.propiedades.margenDerecho&&(z=T.propiedades.margenDerecho),void 0!==T.propiedades.colorLetra&&(A=T.propiedades.colorLetra),void 0!==T.propiedades.font&&(w=T.propiedades.font),o("<div />",{id:"msgPopUp",css:{"text-align":"center",display:"none",position:"fixed",width:P,height:b,"border-radius":"10px 10px 0px 0px","background-color":U,bottom:"0px","font-family":w,right:z,"box-shadow":"2px 2px 13px #888888",color:A}}).appendTo("body"),o("#msgPopUp").css({right:z}),o("<span />",{id:"cerrarmsgPopUp",text:"x",css:{"float":"right",margin:"5px 15px",color:"#A8A8A8",cursor:"pointer","font-size":"26px","font-family":"calibri","font-weight":"900"}}).appendTo("#msgPopUp"),o("<h3 />",{id:"headerMsgPopUp",html:function(){i===!1&&o(this).html(r),i===!0&&o(this).html("<a class='enlacePopUp' href='"+t+"' target='"+n+"' style='text-decoration:none; color:"+p+";' >"+r+"</a>")},css:{color:A,margin:"15px","font-size":a,"text-align":"center",color:p}}).insertAfter("#cerrarmsgPopUp"),o("<img />",{id:"imgmsgPopUp",src:d,css:{width:s},width:s}).insertAfter("#headerMsgPopUp"),o("<h3 />",{id:"footermsgPopUp",html:function(){l===!1&&o(this).html(c),l===!0&&o(this).html("<a class='enlacePopUp' href='"+h+"' target='"+m+"' style='text-decoration:none; color:"+g+";' >"+c+"</a>")},css:{color:A,"font-size":f,"text-align":"center",margin:"15px",color:g}}).insertAfter("#imgmsgPopUp"),o("#cerrarmsgPopUp").hover(function(){o(this).css("color","red")},function(){o(this).css("color","#A8A8A8")}),o(".enlacePopUp").hover(function(){o(this).css("text-decoration","underline")},function(){o(this).css("text-decoration","none")}),o("#cerrarmsgPopUp").click(function(){o("#msgPopUp").slideUp(x)}),setTimeout(function(){o("#msgPopUp").slideDown(x),null!==v&&setTimeout(function(){o("#msgPopUp").slideUp(x)},v)},u)}}(jQuery);
```

Comment: ¿Cómo lo has intentado?

Comment: con una libreria de js llamada jquery magnific popup pero al hacer llamado en el html no me funciona

Comment: `<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 
   $.magnificPopup.open({
     showCloseBtn:true,
     closeOnBgClick:true,
     enableEscapeKey: true,
     closeOnContentClick: true,
     closeBtnInside: true,
     type:'image',
     image: {
      markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
         '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
         '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
        '</div>',
      tError: 'La imagen no puede cargarse.'
     },
     items: {
      src: 'res/bootstrap.png'
     }
    });


</script>`

Comment: Podrías añadir a tu pregunta tu código JS y HTML que estés usando para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: listo ese es el código que estoy utilizando

Comment: Leyendo un poco la documentación dice que requiere Jquery 1.7.2 o superior, me parece que por ahí podría estar el error.

Comment: En realidad deberías cargarla una sola ves a la imagen, la primera ves que visita la pagina las veces siguientes seria preferible que no. puedes guardar una bandera en `sessionStorage` y consultarlo cada ves que cargue la pagina. Créeme es muy molesto que aparezca siempre que ingresas al sitio.

Comment: puedes intentarlo con bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por su apoyo pero encontré la solución a mi propio problema usando siempre el js de Magnific PopUp

```html
<script>

$(document).ready(function() 
            {

   $.magnificPopup.open(
                {
     showCloseBtn:true,
     closeOnBgClick:true,
     enableEscapeKey: true,
     closeOnContentClick: true,
     closeBtnInside: true,
     type:'image',
     image: {
      markup: '<div class="mfp-figure">'+
        '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
        '<div class="mfp-img"></div>'+
        '</div>',
      tError: 'La imagen no puede cargarse.'
     },
     items: {
      src: 'images2.jpg'
     }
                }
            );

            });
</script>
```

El resultado Final fue este:
[image: backgroundpopupimg]

Comment: Recuerda que puedes dar por aceptada tu propia respuesta. [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Eso no es una imagen. Es un contenedor con texto y un botón de Me gusta de Facebook.

Veo que ya estás usando jQuery. Diseñá el popover en HTML de forma normal, ubicalo en un contenedor con position:fixed para que esté por encima de todo el contenido del sitio, y mostralo con jQuery. Acá tenés un ejemplo:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dzXqRJ